# ¿Como usar with y where para excluir un dato?

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo una tabla llamada Property, y otra llamada PropertyType (cada una con su modelo y controlador), en Property tengo el metodo para acceder a su propertyType:

```
public function propertyType() {
    return $this->belongsTo(PropertyType::class, 'property_type_id');
}
```

Mi tabla PropertyType tiene 2 campos, id y name.

Ahora necesito un método para listar todos los property que hayan, pero que omita aquellos que tengan una relación con propertyType de name "Parking Lot" (where name <> 'Parking Lot'), sin embargo, no se como hacer esto.

```
/*Actualizado*/
```

Mi metodo actualmente esta asi, pero no me retorna todos los Property

```
public function getProperties() {
    $properties = Property::with(['propertyType' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('property_type.name', '<>', 'Parking Lot');
    }])
    ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
    ->get();

    return $properties;
}
```

Comment: _pero no me retorna todos los Property_ ¿Acaso debería retornarlos todos? No entiendo esta parte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al acceder a los registros de un modelo, para limitar sus resultados en función de la [existencia de una relación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence), existe el método `has()`.
Por ejemplo, teniendo ya definida la relación como `propertyType`:

```php
// Obtiene todas la Property que tienen al menos un PropertyType...
$properties = Property::has('propertyType')->get();
```

Si necesitas aún más power, puedes usar el método `whereHas()` para poner condiciones "where" en la consulta, lo que te permite agregar restricciones personalizadas a la restricción de relación que hace `has()`.
Por ejemplo:

```php
// Obtiene todas la Property que tienen al menos un PropertyType donde el valor del campo 'name' es distinto de 'Parking Lot'...
$properties = Property::whereHas('propertyType', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('name', '<>', 'Parking Lot');
})->get();
```

Aún así, quizá no sea suficiente, pues traería solo las Property que tengan al menos un PropertyType y no las que no tienen ningún PropertyType relacionado.

Entonces para tu caso:

> listar todos los property que hayan, pero que omita aquellos que tengan una relación con propertyType de name "Parking Lot"

puedes checkar la [ausencia de la relación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) combinada con "where", parecido al ejemplo anterior.

```php
// Obtiene todas la Property que no tienen ningún PropertyType donde el campo 'name' tenga valor 'Parking Lot'...
$properties = Property::whereDoesntHave('propertyType', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('name', 'Parking Lot');
})->get();
```

Lo mismo con with y orderBy:

```php
$properties = Property::whereDoesntHave('propertyType', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('name', 'Parking Lot');
})
->with(['propertyType'])
->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
->get();
```

Comment: Perdón la tardanza al responder... Muchas gracias , me sirvio perfectamente, solo que cuando uso whereDoesntHave, no me lleva el dato de la relación (el with básicamente), como podría hacerlo?

Comment: @Andres `whereDoesntHave()` es sólo para filtrarlo por la ausencia de la relación, para que la consulta devuelva también los objetos relacionados déjale el `with()` y para que ordene los datos, déjale el `orderBy()` como lo estabas haciendo. Edité la respuesta agragando al final como puedes hacerlo.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me sirvió perfectamente